# Can I use “as of today” as a substitute to “nowadays”?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wonder whether it’s ok to use “as of today” just to describe the state of things how they are now without making any assumptions about how the things were beforehand.

For instance, let’s consider a phrase: “As of today child labor is illegal almost everywhere”.

Does the usage of “as of today” necessarily imply that earlier child labor was a case?

Comment: i suppose strictly speaking as of today just means today

Comment: @Toothrot, well, the answer already provided contradicts to your assumption.

Comment: Can anyone explain the number of down-votes? I’m honestly failing to see what’s wrong with my question(

Comment: you seem to be asking about something that can easily be looked up

Comment: @Toothrot once again, your comment contradicts to the answer provided which already hinting that it’s not that simple. I lived in the US for three years and was 100% sure there’s nothing complicated with that phrase. Today I’ve been corrected and googling confused me even more.

Comment: Possibly your lack of research. See http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/as-of-today (which took me only 1 minute to find!).

Comment: you haven't made clear what you are asking.  in common usage, it doesn't mean today.  i said _strictly speaking._

Comment: This is exactly the article I read before asking here. And there’s no evidence that it’s equivalent for today.

Comment: No!  If I heard that I would be led to believe that some important legislation had been passed today.  If nothing has changed today specifically, then just say, “Today, At this point in time, Currently, etc.”

Comment: @Jim can you please leave it as an answer. It would be also helpful if you point out where are you from - may be there are regional differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'As of today' implies (in the UK at least) that whatever it is has started today and was different before, e.g. (going back a few years) "As of today drivers and passengers in private vehicles are legally required to wear seat belts." The day before it was not a legal requirement. So, in my opinion, 'as of today' does not mean 'nowadays'